# How to deal with Libraries which are needed in many projects (+ svn)

Tags: svn, deployment, shared-libraries

Good morning!

We have a SVN-Repository, which holds a VS-Solution. In this solution are many web-projects and each of them is using a JavaScript-Lib which is atm developed in an extra project (let's call it `DemoWeb`) and deployed manually to the other Web-Projects.
This construct has many disadvantages:

1. You can forget a project to copy to when deploying.
2. You can miss some files out
3. You have the same .js-files several times in the SVN-Repository
4. ...

I think that the scenario (many Projects using the same Libs - eg. JavaScript, .dll-files, Images, ...) is very common, so I ask you:
How do you deal with it?
How do you get rid of this disadvantages?
How do you don't loose the references for IntelliSense in VS (eg. CssClass-Checking)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Automated builds for building/deployment
- for intellisense: VS have something called 'add as link' so you can have your js in one place and referense it from all projects : click project->add->existing item, find your files and take a look at 'add' btn, there is a little arrow at the right, use it and choose 'add as link'

Answer (score 3):

**Automate your build and/or deployment routines**.  Look into continuous integration.  Deploying your application should take one step. (a click on a link, execution of a script, etc...)  Anything more than that and you are asking to screw up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But: We would loose the IntelliSense-Features for CssClass-Checking...